# React can't read property of undefined, even though I can see value at console, and it changes the name of the component to <e>

Tags: reactjs, properties, parent-child, state

I'm trying to display a prop of an element ( I can see it in console) 
 the child element (I'm using react materialize):

```
export default class MyLastWorkout extends React.Component {
   render(){
      return (
        <Card results ={this.props.results} 
          className='blue-grey darken-1'
          textClassName='white-text'
          title='Card title'
          actions={[<a href='#'>This is a link</a>]}
        >
          <p > 
            { this.props.results[0].exercise}
          </p>
        </Card>
      )
   }
```

React changes element to `<e>` and even though I see props at console, I can't get them  in `<p>`! I've also tried to use simple div instead, but it didn't work.

Parent Element:

```
var Exercises = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      exercise: "",
      type: "",
      weight: "",
      sets: "",
      reps: "",
      searchTerm: "",
      results: [],
      history: [] 
    }
  },

  getResults: function(){
    return axios.get('/exercisesadd')
    .then(function(response){      
      return response;
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <LastWorkout/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: are you sure this code is rendering? i dont see the render method.

Comment: yes, just added it here, I can see the card, but can't add information to it

Comment: It may so happend that state results is empty initially and hence this.props.results[0].exercise is undefined. Try `{ this.props.results && this.props.results[0].exercise}` or `{this.props.results[0] &&  this.props.results[0].exercise}`

Comment: I've tried to add it to the <p>, but it didn't work, but look like you are right, it's evaluated after the card was created.. still not sure how to fix it though

Comment: Can you add the code for you parent component where LastWorkout is called

Comment: Added a part of parent element, post request finds values in db, I also think that the problem inside the child element, since I can see the result array in console, but can't display it.  I also can't understand why the name "MyLastWorkout" was changed to "<e>"

Comment: Is this normal that you doesn't pass any props to `LastWorkout` ? I can't see how is passed `this.props.results`. Where in the code did you try `console.log`. Could you created a jsfiddle to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I added constructor to the child element, and it works now !

Comment: You probably are using anonymous function, which will mask the `this`.